# Can $f t_1 t_2 \cdots t_n ~u$ be a valid syntax for a term?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If $f$ is a function of arity $n$ and $t_i$ are terms and $u$ is **any** string of symbols over some specified language $\mathcal{L}$, then can
$$
f t_1 t_2 \cdots t_n ~u
$$
be a valid syntax of a term My understanding says that it can’t be a valid syntax because even if $u$ is some variable or constant then also it won’t be operated by $f$ because of arity. And if $u$ involves some other function $g$ then it might be against unique readability to not include the functions at left most of the string.

Comment: See [similar post regarding formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872385/why-is-the-unique-readability-of-wffs-important). The fact is obvious, but at the start of a math logic course can be helpful learn how to prove it in order to practice with structural induction proof.

Comment: You'd need to show that $t_n u$ isn't itself a term. Luckily, no term of a language of predicate logic is a non-empty initial segment of another: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940741/proof-that-no-term-of-a-language-of-predicate-logic-is-a-non-empty-initial-s

Comment: @TomKern Once you know that no term is a nonempty initial segment of another, this proof is complete, because $ft_1\dots t_n$ is a term and is an initial segment of $ft_1\dots t_nu$.

Comment: @TomKern Thank you so much.